# Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(): No such Entity

Tags: java, extjs, gwt, gxt, jsni

I am creating an `ExtJS` model using `JSNI`. But when I try to run the application, it says:

> Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(): No such Entity "NameValueModel"

`NameValueModel` is in the same class. 
Can you please tell what should I give in schema and Ext.define ? 
It should be only the class name or something else?

```
private native void createModel0() /*-{
    $wnd.Ext.define('NameValueModel', {
        config : {
            name : 'Z',
            value : 0,
        },
        constructor : function(config) {
            this.initConfig(config);
            return this;
        },
        schema : "NameValueModel"
    });
}-*/;
```